# Percent-encoded dot in .NET Uri

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, uri

I'm trying to send a request to a web service that *requires* certain `.` characters in the request URI to be percent-encoded as `%2e`. I'm having trouble sending a request from .NET, because when I construct the `Uri` instance it replaces the `%2e` characters with `.` characters. How can I work around this issue to send the web request in the form required by the service?

**Edit:** Here is how I'm constructing the request:

```
Uri uri = ...;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.UserAgent = "MyUserAgent";
```

I have attempted the following:

- Constructing the `Uri` instance using `UriTemplate.BindByName`
- Constructing the `Uri` instance, then using `UriBuilder` to try to insert the `%2e` characters.

  ```
  Uri uri = "...";
  UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
  builder.Path = builder.Path.Replace(".", "%2e");
  uri = builder.Uri;
  ```
- Constructing the `Uri` while setting the `dontEscape` constructor argument to `true`.

Comment: What method are you using to send the request? Can't you use a string instead of an `Uri` object?

Comment: what did you try? (as in, can you show us how you try to do that)

Comment: @Guffa `WebRequest.Create` has an overload that takes a `string`, but all it does is create a `Uri` object from the string and call the other constructor.

Comment: @Noctis I added more detail, but the real key here is to create a [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) instance that contains the substring `%2e` in the path component of an HTTP or HTTPS URI.

Comment: did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3857067/1698987) answer ?

Comment: @Noctis Yes, and many more. Most were about URIs with a path segment with a dot at the end, that didn't need to be escaped. This is a completely different situation because the dot isn't at the end, and *must* be escaped.

Comment: I see, I'll take it you tried with a '@' before the string? (just making sure ...)

Comment: The @ before a string changes how you escape characters in the string. Adding it has no effect on `%2e` and doesn't change how the string works once it is created.

Comment: I just ran into this - fortunately, the service I am calling does not **require** the dot to be encoded to %2E. But I find it annoying that `Uri` is doing this automatically and there seems to be no way of disabling it.