# Float parameter in URL using GET

Tags: javascript, php, api, parameter-passing

I want to pass a float parameter to an api using GET.

The URL should look like `/api/controller/action/1.25`

But I get an error because of the **dot**.

The API end point is in PHP and I call the URL from ReactJS.

Apart from replacing . with another character on both ends or using POST, is there any recommended solution to achieve that using GET?

Thanks,
Harris

Comment: This may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856693/a-url-resource-that-is-a-dot-2e

Comment: Ok, no code, but could you at least tell us the exact error you get? Do you control the API, or not? Seems like you do.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I get a 404 error when i put a float instead of an integer. That is probably because the browser reads the dot as a file extension.

Comment: Doesn't the API controller pick up the URL and parse it? Like you do in an .htaccess rewrite?