# mod_rewirte (.htaccess) strange behavior for URLs having ".profile" text

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, mod-rewrite

I got a hosting with WordPress engine installed and inside the root of WP engine folders I've created another web application which is having problems with URLs containing `.profile` word. When this text is added to URL I'm always receiving 404 error.
Here's an example:
WordPress blog URL: `https://mainsite.com`
Sub web application folder name: `webapp`
Sub web application access URL:  `https://mainsite.com/webapp/`
So, when I try to access URL like this: `https://mainsite.com/webapp/login.php?code=user.profile` I'm receiving error 404. At the same time URL like this: `https://mainsite.com/webapp/login.php?code=user.profilb` is working fine (2nd URL got last letter replaced by another symbol).
I think this is an issue with WordPress default mod_rewrite settings, here they are:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I got no clue at all why this could happen with .htaccess file like this. Could you suggest please?

Comment: See @phyzome comment  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856693/a-url-resource-that-is-a-dot-2e

Comment: This ".profile" can be anywhere. I just removed all unnecessary parts of the URL to be easier to understand the issue. I've slightly updated original url, so it's clear that variable is not starting from dot but can be in any part of the url.

Comment: DId you register the query var in your functions.php file? [link]https://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/post/custom-query-string-vars-in-wordpress

Comment: @Jamie_D I don't need URL with ".profile" part to be parsed by WordPress at all. I need it to be properly redirected to sub-folder web-app.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the issue was with `mod_security` of a2hosting. They were blocking all sensitive linux files and folders, like: `.profile`, `.htaccess`, `.bashrc`...
Hope, this will help someone.